# How to inject service inside a module function NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, pinojs

I'm using [pino-logger](https://github.com/pinojs/pino) in my NestJS project to log the activities in my application, and I'm logging the object along with `ReqId` so I can trace the whole activity inside one request. I'd like to use the same "ReqId" in another place as well, but I'm unsure of how to move it outside of the module, so for that, I'm thinking to save that generated `ReqId` into the `CacheManager` but not sure how to inject `CacheManager` class inside `genReqId` function. Please look over the code below.

`app.module.ts`

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    LoggerModule.forRoot({
      pinoHttp: {
        genReqId: (req: any) => {
          // I'm thinking to use CacheManager here but I'm not sure how to inject CacheManager class here
          return req.headers.req_id || uuid(); // from here it generate the request ID and I want to export this ID and use in side an another class
        },
        base: undefined,
        quietReqLogger: true,
        timestamp: false,
      },
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need To create sharable service and import it Imports

```
@Injectable()
export class RequestIdService {
  private reqId: string;

  setRequestId(reqId: string) {
    this.reqId = reqId;
  }

  getRequestId() {
    return this.reqId;
  }
}
```

than import it to logger module

````
  imports: [
    LoggerModule.forRoot({
      pinoHttp: {
        genReqId: (req: any) => {
          this.requestIdService.setRequestId(req.headers.req_id || uuid());
          return this.requestIdService.getRequestId();
        },
        base: undefined,
        quietReqLogger: true,
        timestamp: false,
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [RequestIdService],
    ```

use that service by
````

import { RequestIdService } from './request-id.service';
this.requestIdService.getRequestId()

Comment: this will generate different ID if I use that inside a class.. the issue is I wanted to use the same value that is been generated inside the module..